# How to make hovering over one div to trigger changes in two different divs?

Tags: angular, html, css

I am creating simple website in angular 6, I have section which look as follows

[image]

1. I have four divs each div contain icon as background , `span` with title and paragraph `p` with description
2. I have another div to hold description when icon hovered  which is empyt  goes by the name `what-we-do__right`

> **UPDATE**

Here is the link to the stackblitz for codes

https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-nabar-snoyrg

Here is the html

```
<div class="what-we-do">
  <div class="what-we-do__top">
    <div class="what-we-do__left">
      <h2>What we
        <strong>do</strong>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="what-we-do__right">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="animation">
    <div class="center">
      <div class="sat1">
        <span>Managed</span>
        <strong>Service</strong>"
        <p>Managed Service gives our customers the opportunity to reduce the costs of the project and guarantees higher standards
          of work, while maintaining complete control over the different phases of our consultants working progress.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sat2">
        <span>Managed</span>
        <strong>Service</strong>"
        <p>Managed Service gives our customers the opportunity to reduce the costs of the project and guarantees higher standards
          of work, while maintaining complete control over the different phases of our consultants working progress.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sat3">
        <span>Managed</span>
        <strong>Service</strong>"
        <p>Managed Service gives our customers the opportunity to reduce the costs of the project and guarantees higher standards
          of work, while maintaining complete control over the different phases of our consultants working progress.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sat4">
        <span>Managed</span>
        <strong>Service</strong>"
        <p>Managed Service gives our customers the opportunity to reduce the costs of the project and guarantees higher standards
          of work, while maintaining complete control over the different phases of our consultants working progress.</p>

      </div>
      <h3>
        <span>IT</span>
        <strong>Outsourcing</strong>
      </h3>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is css I have tried on one icon.

```
.sat1:hover p span strong,{
   visibility: visible;
    background: url('/assets/images/ico_1_dark.png') center center no-repeat #d9e5ca
}

 .sat1 p{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80px;
    margin-left: 700px;
    color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.sat1 span strong{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80px;
    margin-left: 700px;
    color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

But my solution does not work as expected ,

I am newbie please help, how can achieve what I want ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you please provide a working example in live code viewer like https://stackblitz.com/? It's easier to run and edit the code.

Comment: All of this is one component?

Comment: @Chybie  sorry guys I had problems with my computer : here is link to stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-nabar-snoyrg

Comment: @PalSingh as you wish to solve the issue, its just css  here is the link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-nabar-snoyrg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use variables in your component for each title, and you change those values depending on which button you are hovering.

In your html you just show those variables with interpolation : eg {{variable}}.

Please see this example :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-nabar-eb7bix

Comment: Thanks for the cool answer , I was concetrating only on css, but you opened my eyes for next project to think outside the box :D ,

Answer (score 1):

I refactor your code. There is a better way of doing this. Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-hover. Here is the summary of refactoring:

1. Your CSS work out of the box, I did not touch that.
2. Move all your services to a `list` variable, easier to manage content and you can just loop the list in UI using `*ngFor`, less bloated template.
3. Use a variable `selectedId` to store current `mouseover` item id.
4. Use a get only variable `selectedItem` to get the selected item or default item.
5. Streamline your template to use the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

As Chybie said, it's better with a stackblitz example, but you could try :

```
<div class="sat1" (mouseenter)="showText(1)" (mouseleave)="showText(0)">

<div *ngIf="showText1">
  <p>Managed Service gives our customers the opportunity to reduce the costs of 
  the project and guarantees higher standards of work, while maintaining 
  complete control over the different phases of our consultants working 
  progress.</p>
</div>
```

Then in .ts file

```
showText( index ) {
    if (index == 0){
       this.showText1 = false;
       ....
       this.showText4 = false;
    }
    if (index == 1){
       this.showText1 = true;
    }
    ...
    if (index == 4){
       this.showText4 = true;
    }
}
```

This code is really ugly, you could write it much better using and array to hold the state of each text, but wanted to show the basics.

Comment: sorry for late reply here is the link to stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-nabar-snoyrg,

Comment: Is something like this you are trying to do : https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-nabar-eb7bix

Comment: Yes bro exactly, can you put as answer I will accept it,  imeadiately, Thanks a lot , damn your the GOAT